# How to find a constant such that this inequality holds in $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities

Let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a $0 < c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c(u(a)^2+u(b)^2) \leq \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{H^1}^2$ for all $u \in H^1(a,b)$?
 I can't find an explicit bound but I am pretty sure that even $c(u(a)^2+u(b)^2) \leq \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{L^2}^2$ holds for some $c$.

Edit: I formerly wrote $c(u(a)^2+u(b)^2) \leq \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{H^1}$. However I meant to square the right hand side.

Comment: We can assume $u$ to be continuous since every element of $H^1(a,b)$ has a continuous representative, not sure if this is relevant

Comment: As written, such a $c$ cannot exist, because the left hand side scales with $r^2$ and the right with $r$ when considering $r\cdot u$, $r > 0$. If you take the square root on the left, or square the right, things change.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I am trying to show the equivalence of the standard norm and the norm induced by the dot product $<u,v> = \int uv + u' v' dx + u(a)v(a) + u(b) v(b)$

Comment: @DanielFischer your comment made me realize a mistake. I forgot squaring the right side of the inequality. Now it makes a lot mor sense. I am still not sure why it should be true however

Comment: If you move the $c$ to the other side and take square roots, you'll see that in effect you're asking whether evaluation at a point is a continuous linear functional on $H^1(a,b)$. It is. The smallest value of $\lvert u(x)\rvert$ is not larger than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-a}}\lVert u\rVert_{L^2}$, and $\lvert u(y)-u(x)\rvert \leqslant\int_a^b\lvert u'(t)\rvert\,dt\leqslant\sqrt{b-a}\lVert u'\rVert_{L^2}$, thus $$\lvert u(x)\rvert\leqslant\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-a}} + \sqrt{b-a}\biggr)\cdot\lVert u\rVert_{H^1}$$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.